# How to create a nested dictionary?

Tags: powershell

Trying to create nested dictionary using object in powershell but showing error, so is there any way to create like below??

```
$Adress = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[string,string]]
```

Answer (score 2):

`[string,string]` is not in itself a valid type literal. If the inner values should be dictionaries you need to specify `Dictionary[string,string]` as the second type constraint:

```
$nestedDict = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string]]]::new()
```

Comment: Thank You sir, 
how to use add ,remove etc functions for that type of nested dictionary